# cant get my tekst in the middle of my image

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, center

im fighting with my code and cant figure out why i wont get it to work like i want to,
im trying to get the text inside my image to center.

so while i hover over the image the text will appear , 
only now i want it to be in the middle. texy-align: center doesnt work for me?

and got some help here earlyer with other problems so here i am again haha

```css
                         /*content*/

.container {
 width: 940px;
 margin: 70px auto 0;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container .box {
 position: relative;
 width: 300px;
 height: 198px;
 background: #555;
 margin: 5px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: inline-block;
}

.container .box .imgbox {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.container .box .imgbox img {
 transition: transform 2s;
}

.container .box:hover .imgbox img {
 transform: scale(1.2);
}

.container .box .details {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 10px;
 bottom: 10px;
 right: 10px;
 backgound: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 transform: scaleY(0);
 transition: transform .5s;
}

.container .box:hover .details {
 transform: scaleY(1);
}

.container .box .details .content {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px;
 color: #FFF;
}

.container .box .details .content h2 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #FFF;
}

.container .box .details .content p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
                        <!--containers-->
<div class="container">

                        <!--Basis-->
<div class="box">
  <div class="imgbox">
   <img src="images/basis1.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
 <div class="content">
     <h2>Basis</h2>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
                        <!--Standaard-->
<div class="box">
  <div class="imgbox">
   <img src="images/standaard1.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
 <div class="content">
    <h2>Standaard</h2>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
                        <!--Luxe-->
<div class="box">
  <div class="imgbox">
   <img src="images/luxe1.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
 <div class="content">
   <h2>Luxe</h2>
 </div>
  </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're already doing `top:50%` and `translateY 50%`, you have to do the same for X. Use `translate(-50%,-50%)` instead and also set `left:50%;`.

```
.container .box .details .content{
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Demo below;

```css
/*content*/

.container {
  width: 940px;
  margin: 70px auto 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container .box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 198px;
  background: #555;
  margin: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container .box .imgbox {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .box .imgbox img {
  transition: transform 2s;
}

.container .box:hover .imgbox img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.container .box .details {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  backgound: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.container .box:hover .details {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.container .box .details .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.container .box .details .content h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.container .box .details .content p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!--containers-->
<div class="container">

  <!--Basis-->
  <div class="box">
    <div class="imgbox">
      <img src="images/basis1.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Basis</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Standaard-->
  <div class="box">
    <div class="imgbox">
      <img src="images/standaard1.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Standaard</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Luxe-->
  <div class="box">
    <div class="imgbox">
      <img src="images/luxe1.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Luxe</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thnx allot ! i was already playing with the percentages but just couldnt get it to the middle ,kept shifting the wrong way haha thnx allot !

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this also by using `flex`

```css
/*content*/

.container {
 width: 940px;
 margin: 70px auto 0;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container .box {
 position: relative;
 width: 300px;
 height: 198px;
 background: #555;
 margin: 5px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: inline-block;
}

.container .box .imgbox {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.container .box .imgbox img {
 transition: transform 2s;
}

.container .box:hover .imgbox img {
 
}

.container .box .details {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 10px;
 bottom: 10px;
 right: 10px;
 backgound: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 transform: scaleY(0);
}

.container .box:hover .details {
    transform: scaleY(1);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.container .box .details .content {
 display: block;
  width: 100%;
 color: #FFF;
}

.container .box .details .content h2 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #FFF;
}

.container .box .details .content p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!--containers-->
<div class="container">

                        <!--Basis-->
<div class="box">
  <div class="imgbox">
   <img src="images/basis1.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
 <div class="content">
     <h2>Basis</h2>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
                        <!--Standaard-->
<div class="box">
  <div class="imgbox">
   <img src="images/standaard1.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
 <div class="content">
    <h2>Standaard</h2>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
                        <!--Luxe-->
<div class="box">
  <div class="imgbox">
   <img src="images/luxe1.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
 <div class="content">
   <h2>Luxe</h2>
 </div>
  </div>
</div> 
</div>
```